# phpunit: Unable to assertCount efficiently on laravel feature testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

When I try to assertCount() I get this error:

```
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertCount() must be a countable or traversable
```

which means I'm not passing something that is countable.

Here is my Controller, I'm simply returning the collection.

```
 public function index()
    {
        // Get articles
        $articles = Article::all();

        return $articles->toArray();
}
```

Here, I can do `count($articles)` and it will give me the count but `phpunit` is converting this collection of data into another object. Hence, which gives me an error.

i.e

```
/** @test */
    public function a_user_can_view_articles(){

        factory('App\Article')->create();

        $response = $this->get('api/articles');

        $this->assertCount(1, $response);

    }
```

But I if `assertCount` it like:

```
$this->assertCount(1, $response->baseResponse->data);
```

`it works`.
I don't wanna do it all the time. Is there anyway i can do it in a better manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it converts it to json, use

```
$this->assertCount(1, $response->json());
```

Comment: Oh my lord. I clearning stated `jsonResponse{baseReponse{}}`.. Thanks buddy. You saved me alot of trouble.